# format is not rewritten in visio, replace shape method

Tags: vba, visio

I am rewriting master using the replaceshape method in VISIO.

I want to replace the format of shape data, but not to replace the value of shape data.

When I check the "ReplaceLockShapeData = 1", both format and value of shape data replaced by new master.

How can I change the format only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> both format and value of shape data replaced by new master.

You mean shape data of sub-shapes ?

Comment: Thanks.
I want to make the shape with shape_data which format is inherited from the new master, and which value is inherited by original shape.
Its' impossible ?

Comment: I think it would be easier to change the formatting of master-shape in the document stencil ?

Comment: Since the number of documents is expected to exceed 100, it is unrealistic to change the formatting of master-shape one by one.

As an idea,
####
newvsoshape.cells ("Prop.sd1"). Format = newvssxshape.cells ("Prop.sd1"). Format
####
newvsoshape.cells ("Prop.sd1"). Value = oldvsoshape.cells ("Prop.sd1"). Value

I haven't tried this notation yet.

I do not yet know how to iteratively process when there are a large number of Prop.sd1, Prop.sd2, Prop.sd3.

Comment: As I said, newvsoshape.cells ("Prop.sd1.format") =   newvssxshape.cells ("Prop.sd1.format") works.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your previous comment. were you able to enumerate existing shape data properties ?